# Transform a table from WIDE to LONG (pivoting) with duplicate rows (tidyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

There is a long table which should be transformed to a wide table,
but there are duplicate rows according the variable *pseudonym*

```
df_long <- data.frame(
    pseudonym = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c"),
    score = c(0.3 ,0.7, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9 , 0.8),
    topic = c("car", "tree", "hill", "tree", "car", "hill"))
```

```
> df_long
  pseudonym score topic
1         a   0.3   car
2         a   0.7  tree
3         a   0.2  hill
4         b   0.4  tree
5         c   0.9   car
6         c   0.8  hill
```

I tried to transform this table in the following wide table:

```
df_wide <- data.frame(
  pseudonym = c("a", "b", "c"),
  car = c(0.3 , NA, 0.9),
  hill = c(0.2, NA, 0.8),
  tree = c(0.7, 0.4, NA))
```

```
> df_wide
  pseudonym car hill tree
1         a 0.3  0.2  0.7
2         b  NA   NA  0.4
3         c 0.9  0.8   NA
```

The code

```
df_long %>%
  spread(key = topic, value = score)
```

produces the message **Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 137108 rows:**

Another try with *pivot_wider()*

```
df_long %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = topic, values_from = score)
```

leads to **Warning message:
Values in `score` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.**
and list colums.

I think I have to set another parameter of pivot_wider() correctly or combine it with grouping.
A good solution will be very helpfull.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't get the warning you say you do with `pivot_wider`, btw. I'm on R-3.5.3, dplyr-0.8.3, tidyr-1.0.0. (Nor do I get the error with `spread`. It must be a version thing.)

Comment: @r2evans Sorry it was a typing error. I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `pivot_wider` you usually have to specify `names_from`, `values_from`, and `id_cols`. This seems to work for me.

`pivot_wider(df_long, names_from = "topic", values_from = "score", id_cols = "pseudonym")`

Comment: You don't always need `id_cols`. When not provided, [it defaults](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/master/R/pivot-wide.R#L219) to the rest of the variables.

Comment: Thank you. With the paramter **id_cols** ist works!